# How to cite a bookchapter that is accepted and To appear?

Tags: citations, formatting, google-scholar, bibtex

I have a book chapter that is accepted and I want to cite it on a conference paper that I should upload its camera ready today. What is the best way to cite it ? here is my bibtex.

```
@inbook{book_chapter2,
      author={Names of authors},
   year= 2019, 
 chapter={chapter title}, 
   title= {Book Name}, 
   publisher= {Springer},
       Editor=  {Edited X and Y}
    Note= {Accepted and To Appear}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
Accepted for publication
```

I've seen it several times and I usually use it like this. You could also use:

```
In press
```

Comment: But when I recompile the file, the edited by does not appear in the output. is that okay ?

Comment: @HebaMohsen That's a LaTeX/BibTeX issue and depends on the reference style.

Comment: It is IEEE conference style. Is my bibtex works fine. When the books appears, the citation will work ?

Comment: @HebaMohsen I don't understand the (new) question but it seems to be LaTeX related and cannot be answered here.

Comment: My question is: will the reference citation appear on google scholar ?

Comment: @HebaMohsen Nobody knows but Google. Sorry. My guess is that it will work but don't ask me why and how Google does anything. It's closed source and, as I said, nobody knows but Google.